# Kill a process if it goes quiet for a certain amount of time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stdout, timeout

I have a utility that has a nasty habit of going quiet and staying there, I already know how long into the process it does this so I am using `timeout` to fight this, but sometimes it does it before that time. Is there a tool similar to `timeout` that will kill the process if it stops directing output to stdout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
zmodload zsh/system
coproc your-command
while :; do
  sysread -t 10 -o 1 <&p && continue
  if (( $? == 4 )); then
    echo "Timeout" >&2
    kill $!
  fi
  break
done
```

The idea being to use the `-t` option of `sysread` to read from `your-command` output with a timeout.

Note that it makes `your-command`'s output a pipe. It may be that `your-command` starts buffering its output when it doesn't go to a terminal, in which case you may find that it doesn't output anything in a while, but only because of that buffering, not because it's *hung* somehow.

You could work around that by using `stdbuf -oL your-command` to restore line-buffering (if your-command uses stdio) or use `zpty` instead of `coproc` to fake a terminal output.

With `bash`, you'd have to rely on `dd` and GNU `timeout` if available:

```
coproc your-command
while :; do
  timeout 10 dd bs=8192 count=1 2> /dev/null <&${COPROC[0]} && continue
  if (($? == 124)); then
    echo Timeout >&2
    kill "$!"
  fi
done
```

Instead of `coproc`, you could also use process substitution:

```
while :; do
  timeout 10 dd bs=8192 count=1 2> /dev/null <&3 && continue
  if (($? == 124)); then
    echo Timeout >&2
    kill "$!"
  fi
done 3< <(your-command)
```

(that won't work in `zsh` or `ksh93` because `$!` doesn't contain the pid of `your-command` there).

Comment: Hi! Thanks, Is it possible you could comment this so I can understand what this is doing?

Answer (score 0):

I'd redirect STDOUT to a file and then use monit's [timestamp testing](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#timestamp_testing) to restart the process if the file's mtime is greater than a threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Actually proposed code:

```
zmodload zsh/system
coproc your-command
while :; do
  sysread -t 10 -o 1 <&p && continue
  if (( $? == 4 )); then
    echo "Timeout" >&2
    kill $!
  fi
  break
done
```

didn't work for me in zsh. It somehow works only if I set 1 sec, even if I set 2 sec - it's didn't.
So another easiest simple way to solve it:
**just run immediately after coproc yourapp:** `(sleep X; killall -9 your-app)&` - or I use in my case:

```
(sleep 5;coproc exit)& - that's just it!!! or even:
(sleep 5;coproc exit&kill -9 $$)& or
(sleep 5;coproc exit&killall -9 your-app-name)&
```

And I just found out, you also need to add *killall -9 sleep* to your loop, in case your program finishes earlier.

I was unable to find an answer for more than 1 hour.
read -t -also didn't work, because my read is inside the loop.

**This is my code with the proposed solution which is doesn't work:**

```
zmodload zsh/system
coproc app
while read -p var; do
if [[ $var =~ "word" ]] then;echo $var;break;fi
  sysread -t 10 -o 1 <&p && continue
  if (( $? == 4 )); then
    echo "Timeout" >&2
    kill $!
  fi
  break
done
if (( $? == **4** )); - here you can put anything, only difference you will not get **Timeout** in terminal, that's it.
```

And as I said this only works if I put sysread -t **1** -o 1 (and will work only for 1 sec), any other numbers - waiting for eternity...
ps. stdbuf also couldn't help. (and I can't use bash, because of their strict policy with opened pipes, and **Bad file descriptor errors**...)